# Find all pairs of values from two arrays which satisfy function in Python using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, equation

In Python 3.6 using NumPy I have two integer values `x,y`, two arrays `rho_values, theta_values` and an equation `rho = x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta)`.

I want to find all pairs of `(rho, theta)` with `rho` in `rho_values` and `theta` in `theta_values` which satisfy the equation.

According to [this](https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-find-the-indexes-where-values-are-true-in-a-boolean-matrix-with-numpy-in-python-/) I came up with the following solution which I expected to give me a boolean matrix with true on every `(rho,theta)` index if `rho, theta` solve the equation:

```
diag = np.linalg.norm((256,400))  # Length of diagonal for some image shape (256,400)
theta_bins = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 300)
rho_bins = np.linspace(-diag, diag, 300)
def solve(x, y):
    return rho_bins == y*np.sin(theta_bins[:,np.newaxis])+x*np.cos(theta_bins[:,np.newaxis])

for x in range(0, 255):
    for y in range(0, 399):
        print(solve(x,y))
```

It does not work. What would be a correct and fast way to do this? Iterating over both arrays is not an option for me since I have many `x,y` values for each of which iterating over both arrays would cost a lot of time.

Comment: Have you occasionally written `row` when you meant `rho` (or vice versa)? Also, you once write `tetha` instead of `theta`.

Comment: @jmd_dk Yes, sorry. I got them mixed up. I edited the question.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html?

Comment: @Dilara Looks interesting, but I would prefer a plain Python and/or Numpy only solution

Comment: @flawr Added the values. The example comes from a part of an implemenation of a Hough Transformation for images. This context should although not be necessary for my question

Comment: Notice you have for x twice, should be for x for y.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) . Use `np.isclose`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, thank you. This actually does. It is also similar to what jmmcd's answer says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, using == with floating-point numbers is a mistake. Consider using an idiom such as abs(x-y)<0.00000001 instead.

Comment: This actually was the problem. I was not familiar with the floating point math in Python

Comment: Great! Notice that pretty much all modern languages use the same floating-point math (IEEE 754) so the same general rule applies in other languages also.